# What is the use of HWND in GetMessage in Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to create two windows. GetMessage will get the messages from both windows.

If I pass the second parameter(HWND) to it. It will only get the messages from this window. How to get the messages from second window?

Comment: Each ```window``` has a unique handle to it aka. ```HWND```. If you pass ```HWND``` for either of windows, it accepts messages for it. Do you mean you'd like to have messages for both simultaneously? Then don't pass any ```HWND```. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage): ```If hWnd is NULL, GetMessage retrieves messages for any window that belongs to the current thread,```

Comment: @Iman Abdollahzadeh I meant to say what will happen if I call `GetMessage(&msg, hwnd1, 0, 0)`. How to get messages for hwnd2?

Comment: if you pass ```NULL``` to ```GetMessage```, it handles all messages for you.

Comment: The `hWnd` parameter for [`GetMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) is a filter. If you want messages for all windows on the calling thread dispatched, don't filter (i.e., pass `NULL`). If you do want to filter and don't want to filter at the same time, then that problem has no solution.

Answer (score 2):

The `hWnd` parameter for [`GetMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) is a filter. It restricts the set of messages being dequeued from the message queue. You can pass one of three values:

- `NULL`: No filtering applied
- A valid window handle: Only messages for this window are retrieved
- `-1`: Only thread messages are retrieved

If you want to process all messages for windows owned by the calling thread, pass `NULL`. You rarely want to filter messages for a particular window, and if you do, you will eventually want to perform an unfiltered `GetMessage()` call. Otherwise, you are left with a broken application, as explained in [The dangers of filtering window messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050209-00/?p=36493).

Comment: I have a function which calls `GetMessage`. So, there will be two function calls to that function. But, it won't be called until first call has returned. What should I do in this situation? Should I create Windows in separate threads?

Comment: That reads like a windowing framework gone wrong, based on the false assumption that there was one message queue per window. The message queue, however, is per thread and services *all* windows created on that thread. You could work around that by spawning a thread per window. But that's both needlessly costly and complex, as well as [painfully difficult](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683). Maybe ask a separate question that explains why you have to filter messages by window in the first place.